# Spring scheduled tasks cannot be run if properties file is placed outside application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

I'm working on a Spring web app, and need to use a Scheduled method that runs in background every certain time, so I created a class "ScheduleDemo", a properties file "schedule.properties" which is placed inside my application, and also added several lines to my applicationContext.xml, and everything is OK.
Now there should be a change that I need to move the schedule.properties file to outside my application, and then I made some changes for my applicationContext.xml, but found the scheduled method cannot run, below is my code, is there any person can provide solutions?

**ScheduleDemo.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:schedule.properties")
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync


Public class ScheduleDemo{

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Scheduled(cron="${email.schedule}")
public void doSomething() {
    logger.info("Test if it is Okay"); 
}
```

}`

**schedule.properties**

```
email.schedule = 0 0 8 ? * WED
```

**applicationContext.xml**

`<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5" /> 
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" /> 
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler" />`

Then when I moved the schedule.properties file outside my application, I made below changes to applicationContext.xml, I tried "file" or "classpath" to point to external schedule.properties file, but not successfully.

**Updated applicationContext.xml**

```
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5" />
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>file:${app.config.location}/schedule.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>`
```